# Sharepoint List event

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, splistitem, splist

Is there a event which is raised when current view of a SharePoint list is changed. For example the current view displays all items in the list and now the user selects a different view say Added by Me, so is there any event raised in such a condition.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What i want to achieve is something like this. I want to create a view such that the list is filtered according to the current user information. This information is coming from an external database. So what i was thinking is if there is any view change event then i could write a listener for it, check which view is selected , if it is the said view then fetch current user and his information from external DB and filter the list values. I am a newbie in SharePoint so don't know if such a thing can be done or not. Is there any other way by which this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such event. The list events ListUpdating, ListUpdated etc. fire when you write changes to the list to the content db.

The following webpage shows you how to create a custom view that filters the information based on the current user:

http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2009/07/16/creating-a-custom-view-that-filters-on-the-current-user.aspx

Creating a view with a custom CAML query filter might solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I had tired using custom CAML query but it didn't work for me as i want to filter the data based on a value from external DB(which depends on the current user) not on current user itself. However, i achieved it using custom filter web part. Hope i made some sense.